# Change value multidimensional array in session Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, multidimensional-array

I have a shopping cart and I want to update the amount of it in the cart session.

This is my cart session:

```
array:1 [▼
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "name" => "Carocroc Lam"
    "image" => "carocroc_lam_15kg.jpg"
    "price" => 45.95
    "unit" => 15
    "name_unit" => "kg"
    "amount" => "2"
  ]
]
```

So I know that I need a foreach to update the item in the shopping cart but when I do that and send it back to the request it only put in the amount of the item.

What I want to receive is that only the amount will be updated and send the whole updated array back tot the shopping cart.

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

So, say you save the cart array as `$cartItems`, you can do:

```
foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
  $cartItem['amount'] = NEWAMOUNTVALUE;
}
```

If you need further help please clarify in the comments!

Comment: found the solution see my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
$cartItems = new Collection();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $cartItem = new CartItem();
    $cartItem->amount = $item['amount'];
    $cartItem->save();
    $cartItems.push($cartItem);
}

return $cartItems;
```

If you want to store it in a collection and return it properly you can use this code. If you want to edit the array directly and then do the update you can use the above code from @party-ring with a bit of extra information below.

```
foreach ($cartItems as &$cartItem) {
  $cartItem['amount'] = NEWAMOUNTVALUE;
  CartItem::update($cartItem);
}

return $cartItems;
```

Comment: found the solution see my comment

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself
I did the following and it worked.

```
foreach ($currentCart as $item){
  $currentCart[1] = [
      'name' => $item['name'],
      'image' => $item['image'],
      'price' => $item['price'],
      'unit' => $item['unit'],
      'name_unit' => $item['name_unit'],
      'amount' => $item['amount'] = $request->input('amount'),
  ];
  $request->session()->put('cart', $currentCart);
}
```

Comment: Could you use `$item` instead of `$currentCart[1]`? Because the foreach loop is going through every item of `$currentCart`?

Comment: What party-ring is trying to say is that you target the first item (Probably the second since PHP starts numbering arrays from 0 onwards)

So instead of targetting it dynamically you are only changing the value of only one item in the array. 

So use $item directly like in our examples or rewrite your foreach loop to include the index on which item you are currently looping. 

foreach ($currentCart as $index => $item)

Then you can access it with $currentCart[$index] =